# How to configure kernel to enable eCryptfs and Overlayfs filesystems in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration-files, ecryptfs

I'am trying to use privexec program in Ubuntu but according to  http://www.onarlioglu.com/privexec/ site, they say that "Don't forget to enable ecryptfs and overlayfs support." at the 2. step of installation. I can't find the way to accomplish this job. Can you direct me to solve it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel configuration with

```
make menuconfig
```

provides UI mechanism for search configuration options.

Just press key `/` and input part of the option's name, e.g. "ecrypt" (search is case-insensitive).

Resulted list will enumerate options, contained searched string. For each option its description will be shown. Also it will give place in configuration hierarchy, where option can be set.

Option which enable particular filesystem support is usually named as `<fs-name>_FS`, where `fs-name` is name of the filesystem in uppercase.